# How do I create and use host files in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mpi

I'm trying to run an MPI program with "mpiexec -n 6 ./myprogram", but I get the following eror:

"There are not enough slots available in the system to satisfy the 6
slots that were requested by the application:

./mpi

Either request fewer slots for your application, or make more slots
available for use." etc

I have cores = 4, logical processors = 8 on my laptop.

I've tried oversubscribe and --use-hwthread-cpus but I still cannot use n=6 threads. how do I use more than 8 threads?

Comment: which versions of Ubuntu and Open MPI are you using? did you rebuild it yourself or is it the one that comes with Ubuntu? `mpirun --oversubscribe -np 6 ./myprogram` should work for what it's worth

Comment: I made a silly mistake somewhere. But thank you.